# Display Message box and windows form in Windows Service c#

Tags: c#, windows

I need to display Message Box and Windows Forms through windows service by using c#. Anyone Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot (easily) do this directly from the service's process. As descibed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), there is a way to create an interactive service, that is able to send/process windows messages and display windows.

**But**: Since Windows Vista, all services run in a separate user session, named "session 0". Thus, all windows displayed by services, are displayed in that session. It is theoretically possible (I have even done that once, just for fun), to switch to this session and view these windows, but this would hardly be of use in real life.

My advice would be to create a separate gui application (maybe one with a nice tray icon), that communicates with your service via e.g. TCP/IP or a database. This application can then handle any required user interaction and do the appropriate interaction with the service's process.